# How to serialize/deserialize an enumeration in protobuf-c

Tags: c, enumeration, protocol-buffers

I have the following message with an enumeration:

```
message testmessage {

    enum testenum {
        alpha = 1;
        beta = 2;

        }

        required unit32 datapoint = 1;
        required uint32 location = 2;
        required int32  displacement = 3;

    }
```

I know how to serialize/pack and deserialize/unpack the normal required fields but not the enum.  There doesn't seem to be any example of this on the protobuf-c website http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/ An example of how to do this with c would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html you would probably have to actually use the enum.

Try adding:

```
 optional testenum enumerated = 4;
```

below

```
 required int32  displacement = 3;
```

and cross yoyr fingers